# How to clear inherited customErrors elements in Web.config?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, web-config, custom-errors

As the article [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) says

> the Web.config file for a specific Web
>   site contains settings that apply to
>   the Web site and inherit downward
>   through all of the ASP.NET
>   applications and subdirectories of the
>   site.

I have these settings for a "parent" application

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

but need only these for a "child" application

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

The article also says

> In collections, configuration settings
>   are typically added to the collection
>   via an **add** child element, removed by
>   key name via a **remove** child element,
>   or the entire collection can be
>   cleared via a **clear** child element. An
>   added setting in a child configuration
>   file overrides a setting of the same
>   key name in a parent configuration
>   file unless duplicates are allowed.

But unfortunately this is illegal for some reason

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    <clear/>
<customErrors/>
```

So the question is how to clear inherited customErrors elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add in the inheritInChildApplications="false" XML element to your parent's (top level) web.config?

```
<location inheritInChildApplications=”false”>
```

reference:
- http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/133041.aspx

Comment: Should be noted that altering the parent will also affect all other "children", not just the application in question.

Answer (score 0):

[CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) isn't a collection like other config settings - you're not `<add />`ing the error handlers, so you can't clear them - indeed looking at the docs, the only Child of the CustomeErrors element is `<error>`.

Also, having set the child application to "RemoteOnly" you aren't supplying any custom errors to show to remote users - is that really what you want? Shouldn't you at least be supplying a different DefaultRedirect? Otherwise you'll be showing users the useless yellow "There was an error, but I can't show you the details" page.

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC HandleErrorAttribute to set custom error page.